# Why does g++ optimize out a critical section of the following code?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

The following code causes a crash in my program, because

```
void fractalizeSegment() {
        // Assume next != NULL
        double deltaX = next->x - x;
        double deltaY = next->y - y;

        // Add 3 new points labeled a1, a2, a3 from this to next
        Point a3(x + 2.0*deltaX/3.0, y + 2.0*deltaY/3.0, next);
        double sqr3 = std::sqrt(3.0);
        Point a2(x + deltaX/2.0 - sqr3*deltaY/2.0,
             y + deltaY/2.0 + sqr3*deltaX/2.0,
             &a3);
        Point a1(x + deltaX/3.0, y + deltaY/3.0, &a2);

        next = &a1;
    }
```

Is somehow optimized to

```
void fractalizeSegment() {
    next = &a1;
}
```

The method is called on p0 = {x = 0, y = 0, next = 0x7fffffffe100},
which point to p1 = {x = 1, y = 0, next = 0x0}.

By analyzing the program in the debugger I found that when I'm in the method fractalizeSegment:

```
a1 = {x = 6.9533558075099091e-310, y = 6.9533558075098597e-310, next = 0x7fffffffe190}
```

In address a1.next there is

```
a2 = {x = 6.9533558074508189e-310, y = 4.9406564584124654e-324, next = 0x34}.
```

Trying to deference (*a2.next).next causes a segmentation fault.

Why does g++ optimize my code like this? How can I prevent it?

The current workaround I found was printing out the values of a1, a2, and a3,
this prevented the optimization.

Comment: Perhaps it does *not* assume that `next != NULL`? GCC very aggressively exploits undefined behavior when optimizing code like this.

Comment: `next = &a1;` is going to immediately dangle.

Comment: Adding a if(next != NULL) around the code doesn't change the behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a1` is a local automatic variable that will be destroyed upon returning from the function, so any use of `*next` after that will be undefined. The compiler thinks that surely you will not use those values so why bother computing them.

You probably want to create `a1` in the heap:

```
next = new Point(x + deltaX/3.0, y + deltaY/3.0, &a2); //no need of a1.
```

Maybe also `a2` and `a3` should be dynamically allocated, but that depends on the implementation of `Point`, that you did not show.

And remember to `delete` the allocated objects somewhere.

Comment: "in the heap"? Surely "on the heap".

Comment: You’re really quibbling on “in” vs “on”? The latter is far more idiomatic than the former, which is much more accurate.

Comment: @tambre: Well, I'm not a native speaker, and I have a difficulty with _in_ vs _on_... A quick search on google reveals that _on_ is used about twice more than _in_ on that context (in that context?), but both are regularly used. Nevertheless, I think that the meaning is clear anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, it was directed at **tambre**, but your analysis is exactly opposite: “in” and ”on” are indeed “former” and “latter”, because “on” is more idiomatic than the more accurate “in”. I am **disagreeing** with **tambre**’s giving **rodrigo** a hard time about chosing “in” over “on” — both work, and **rodrigo**’s usage is not incorrect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: About the `&a2` maybe it is incorrect, maybe not. That depends on whether `Point` keeps a reference to that passed point (as a linked list). If that is the case, then `&a3` is also wrong and all of them need to by dynamically allocated. If that pointer is only used as a reference and not kept, then all is fine.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: But from the comments, probably `Point` is a linked list of points, so all of them should be _newed_. I've added a note about that.

Comment: An entertaining read on what an optimizing compiler could do with undefined behavior: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633